# React-Router-Dom No effect when clicking <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Presently I'm having an issue with my Navigation bar. When I click it it does not even change the URL address.

Note: I'm just using the lastest version of `react` and `react-router-dom": ^4.4.0-alpha.1`. No redux here.

Here is the `index.js`

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import App from './components/App';
 import './index.scss'
 import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

 ReactDOM.render(<Router><App /></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is my `App.js` I cut a lot out for brevity.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
 import Home from "./Home";
 import Form from "./Form";
 import Navigation from "./Navigation";
 import About from "./About";

 class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
       this.state = {
          isLoggedIn: null
      };
     }

    render(props) {
     return (
      <div>
      <Navigation
      {...props}
        isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}
       />
       <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
         <Route
           path="/about"
           render={() => {
            return <About />;
            }}
           />
          <Route 
            path="/story/create" 
            render={(props )=> {
            return <Form {...props} />;
            }} 
           />
         </Switch>
       </div>
      );
     }
    }

  export default App;
```

And Lastly, my `Navigation.js`

```
 import React from "react";
 import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
 import Login from './Login'
 import { Tab, Tabs } from "react-materialize";

 export default function Navigation(props) {
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
   let loggedState;
   if (isLoggedIn) {
   loggedState = (
  <div>
    <Tab title="Profile">
    <Link to="/user/:id/profile">
      Profile
    </Link>
    </Tab>

    <Tab title="Log Out">
     <Link to="/logout" onClick={props.handleLogOut}>
        Log Out

    </Link>
    </Tab>
  </div>
);
} else {
loggedState = (
  <Tab title="Login">
  <Login
   isLoggedIn={props.isLoggedIn}
   handleLogIn={props.handleLogIn}
  />
  </Tab>
  );
  }
    return (
  <Tabs className="">
    <Tab title="Home">
     <Link to="/">
      Home
      </Link>

     </Tab>
  <Tab title="All Stories">
  <Link to="/all_stories">
    All Stories
  </Link>
  </Tab>
  <Tab title="Write a Story">
  <Link to="/story/create">
    Write A Story
  </Link>
  </Tab>
  {loggedState}
</Tabs>
 )}
```

I think it would be helpful to mention that this issue is contain only to my navbar (functional) component. I have `<Link>`'s linking to other pages on my app they work just fine, it is only this one that is giving an issue.

I originally thought it was because I wasn't using `withRouter`, but after looking around on StackOverflow, it seems that that is only needed when using `react-redux`.

I have also, considered downgrading `react-router-dom`, but I couldn't find any other posts on this issue that mentioned that. It seems that most others only have this issue because they did not do `Route exact path="/"`, but I think the way I did mine, it should still work correctly.

Thank you greatly in advance.

Comment: Requesting styles of tabs. Suppose that there could be some `pointer-events: none`, for example

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you're facing this issue because there is a `click` event listener with `event.preventDefault()` added to `.tab` or `.tabs`. You can fix it by taking one of the approaches below:

- move `Link`s outside of `.tab` / `.tabs`
- get rid of `preventDefault` or remove tabs `eventListener` itself
- use a tab component instead (for example [react-tabs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs))

BTW, I don't see any need for `tabs` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've just updated with your suggestions, BUT when I wrap the links around the tabs, still nothing happens, you can see the link change at the bottom of Google chrome, but not in the URL so instead I wrapped the tab around link, and I get the peculiar effect that can be seen here https://storyteller-ss.surge.sh/

Comment: The effect is that it displays the link text to click on, which actually links to the page.

Comment: Just get rid of `Tab`s, you don't need them

Comment: The tabs are what's attaching the style to my site, I was hoping there would be away to incorporate the links into them without making the page reload

Comment: You're building Single Page App. There won't be full page reload, as if you were using `<a href=.. />`. To apply styles just provide a `style` or `className` prop to your `Link` like so: `<Link className="myLink" style={{ padding: '10px' }} to=...>`